# installing mysql as a gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, windows, installation, rubygems

i want to develop rails 3 apps using mysql on windows 7 (64 bit) and i have installed mysql via the msi download from the mysql site.

my question is that do i still need to install the mysql gem?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The mysql gem provides the ruby bindings, so yes, you need to install this.

With Rails 3 you should use the mysql2 gem rather than the mysql gem.

Comment: I can confirm this answer. Also dont install mysql 5.5 as i did because it wont work easily. Install the stable version of 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proper solution for anyone interested, that doesn't mess up your current installation of mysql server

1. Download a zip file with mysql server 5.1 NOT the msi one. Make sure it's 32-bit NOT 64-bit. ([From here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html))
2. Since there is no installer file with this, create a folder c:\mysql-gem-install  - you can remove it once you finish.
3. Extract all the files from the zip file into the folder you just created.
4. now run this command

   gem install mysql2 --  '--with-mysql-lib="c:\mysql-gem-install\lib\opt"  --with-mysql-include="c:\mysql-gem-install\include"'

I just installed mysql2 gem v. 0.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do. The mysql gem is a ruby driver (interface) to connect to the mysql database.

You should use [mysql2](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) gem instead with Rails3.